# Highly recommended Swift course that focuses particularly on touch (ideally video course)?

Tags: ios, swift, touch

Does anyone recommend a course on Swift that deals a lot with touch instead of the usual logic? If this type of question doesn't belong here, let me know. I know most questions here involve fixing specific code, but I figure this would be good for people to find as well.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What do you mean by touch?

Comment: Touch logic like on an iPhone or iPad screen (drawing, dragging, etc.). Sorry for not clarifying

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you got an iPad and if you are new to programming I think "Swift Playgrounds", which ships with iOS 10 is pretty awesome and fun.

If you already know how to program look at this: 
https://itunes.apple.com/us/course/developing-ios-9-apps-swift/id1104579961

It's free and awesome ;).